# spring project not displaying bengali font

Tags: java, css, spring, maven, spring-mvc

In my project I want to diplay a message in bengali..So,I have:

**style.css**

```
    @font-face {
      font-family: 'Siyam Rupali';
      src: url('../fonts/SiyamRupali.eot?version=1.070');
      src: local('Siyam Rupali'),
       url('../fonts/SiyamRupali.woff?version=1.070') format('woff'),     
         url('../fonts/SiyamRupali.ttf?version=1.070') format('truetype');
      font-style: normal;

    }

.tabs {
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px auto;
    font-family: 'Siyam Rupali';

}
```

I have "message.properties"  on WEB-INF folder.
message.properties is:

```
tab1.name = \u09AC\u09BE\u0982\u09B2\u09BE
```

I have **spring-servlet.xml**

```
<bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="/WEB-INF/messages" />
         <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />

    </bean>
```

I am using maven,So,In **Pom.xml** I have:

```
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
<project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
```

In my jsp page I have:

```
    <%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<section class="tabs">
    <spring:message code="tab1.name"/>
</ssection>
```

But the message is showing as `question mark..(????)`.. why??

Answer (score 3):

it's a bit late, but I also faced the same problem, so I would like to share how I solved this, with an hope that it will help someone in the future. Also, this is not particular to Bangla fonts, also for any other unicode fonts.

First of all, your css looks fine. This is how I added the fonts. Here is my .css file where I include the fonts:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Siyam Rupali';

    src: url('../fonts/SiyamRupali.eot');

    src: local('Siyam Rupali'),
        url('../fonts/SiyamRupali.eot')     format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('../fonts/SiyamRupali.woff')    format('woff'),
        url('../fonts/SiyamRupali.ttf')     format('truetype');

    font-style: normal;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Siyam Rupali', Fallback, sans-serif;
}
```

You can still use specific font-family on a tag without any problem.

Next comes your resource file. This is an well known problem with IDEs, they don't often create files with necessary encoding (most of the time in ASCII). Open your message properties files in notepad and save them as UTF-8. Also from your IDE's file encoding settings, make sure the properties files are UTF-8.
[See this picture](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_YwswPsft2Odk95Q2hqWFVKR00/view)

Next comes configurations, in your html (or template pages) add meta property charset='UTF-8'.

In your spring configuration, (I was using java based configuration with Thymeleaf template engine, xml configuration and jsp+jstl view resolver configuration will be similar as far as I know)

```
@Configuration
public class ThymeleafConfig {

    @Bean
    public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource resource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        resource.setBasename("classpath:i18n/messages");
        resource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return resource;
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        ServletContextTemplateResolver resolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/html/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        resolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
        resolver.setOrder(1);
        resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        engine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        return engine;
    }

    @Bean
    public ThymeleafViewResolver thymeleafViewResolver() {
        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

**It is very important to note that**, your **view resolver bean** (in my case, ThymeleafViewResolver) must set character encoding as UTF-8 and as message source, use **ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource** and specify character encoding as UTF-8. Or take my word, set UTF-8 anywhere and everywhere you can.

Hope this helps.

Comment: If nano progga font is from [this WP theme](https://github.com/nanodesigns/nano-progga), then please note that, this font is simply an icon font, it doesn't contain any Bengali glyphs.

Comment: Yes, I later removed that as I was only using Siyam Rupali. I will update the post.